Why can't my IDE decide if my variable is Defined or not?
I'm building an adventure game as a fun way to teach myself python and I've run into an odd error. I've split my code out into multiple files for ease of management because its going to get pretty big before I'm done.
Right now I have a handful of items defined by a class held in a file called Item and referenced in the rooms they will be found in by a class in a file called Room.
When I created the files everything seemed to work with no errors reported.
Then I made a couple of minor edits to the file and VS:Code decided that the items called from the Item file in the Room file were undefined variables. They change back and forth as I add or remove a single unrelated character.
Screenshots below of both states:


Can anyone tell me what is going on here?!?

please remove the picture of text and replace it with the text

If I do that you won't be able to see the error.

then at least add the text...  most people will not look at pictures of text ... others cannot view pictures
